# Would it be possible to have links in a question open in a new tab?

Tags: feature-request

I keep finding myself forgetting to open links in a new tab and losing track of where the question I was reading is at.

I don't see any cases that someone would be reading a question and not want a link in the question to open in a new window or tab. So would it be possible to just make this the default?

**Edit**

Since it looks like the answer is just going to be *no* I am going to add on some additional comments that I would like some clarification on.

Some of the prior reasoning for not wanting this feature have been:

> I expect my programs to leave me in control. Please stop trying to
>   mess that up

and

> The website should not open new windows. As already mentioned, you can
>   do it yourself when you want.

And many more along the same lines. This is great and all, but if this is the true reasoning, why does chat open links in a new tab?

It would make me feel much better if I could at least get a consistent reasoning.

Comment: Use the middle mouse button.

Comment: @endolith Either you didn't read what I said or you also fall into the group of people who's answer is "just do what you already said you don't want to do".

Comment: Have you seen http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/59563 ?

Comment: @endolith yes, I mentioned it in a comment on Matt's answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked this very same question on meta.superuser.com - https://meta.superuser.com/questions/2173/default-or-editable-link-target-in-editor

The answer was no.

Comment: Interesting. Apparently SE thinks that Google is doing it all wrong in gmail. ;-)

Comment: Although, my question is somewhat different from those. I am fine with most links the way they are now. I am talking specifically about those links that are in questions.

Comment: @kellenjb, it seems the overall community votes that it should [leave it up to your browser](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2275/make-links-posted-by-users-open-in-a-new-window). If you ctrl click or such to control or get your browser default set.

Comment: @Kortuk yeah, guess I have to admit defeat. Kind of annoying for the answer to be "just do what you already said you don't want to do".

Comment: @kortuk I don't believe there is a browser default for wanting links from inside a question to be opened in a new tab, no way for the browser to be aware of this. There is the script linked to in one of those answers that can be used, still annoying though.

Comment: @kellenjb, i thought years ago my opera defaulted to new tab unless specifically told otherwise, I get that you are talking about a more constrained situation

Answer (score -1):

I wouldn't want this to change.  I like to keep various windows in specific places on the screen, and it's annoying when I click on a link and a new browswer pops up in some random location.  Please, let's not have this site be like too many other obnoxios sites and pollute my screen with extra windows.

Comment: I wasn't asking for a new window, just a new tab. Basically I would want it to act exactly like gmail (and I assume every other email program out there) does. I've never known anyone to think gmail polluted the screen. But it doesn't really matter since I am clearly out voted on this one.